# Solve the equation $\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{2x-1}+x=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Find $x\in R$ satisfy $$\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{2x-1}+x=4$$

---

The root of equation very bad

**My try 1:**

Let $\sqrt[3]{x+2}=a;\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=b\Rightarrow a^3-b^3=3-x$

Have: $a+b=4-x$

=>Root of a system of equation bad, too

**My try 2:**

Use quality $\sqrt[3]{a}\pm \sqrt[3]{b}=\frac{a\pm b}{\sqrt[3]{a^2}\mp \sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}}$ :

$\sqrt[3]{x+2}-ax+\sqrt[3]{2x-1}-bx=4-x$

Need find $ax$, $bx$ but it's very bad, too

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%2B2%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B2x-1%7D%2Bx%3D4

Comment: try $x+2=2x-1$ maybe

Answer (score 2):

to solve this equation use $$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$$
$$(\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=4-x)^3\\x+2+2x-1+3\sqrt[3]{x+2}.\sqrt[3]{2x-1}(\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{2x-1})=(4-x)^3$$ put $\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=4-x  \\$  so 
$$3x+1+3\sqrt[3]{x+2}.\sqrt[3]{2x-1}(\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{2x-1})=(4-x)^3\\
3x+1+3\sqrt[3]{x+2}.\sqrt[3]{2x-1}(4-x)=(4-x)^3\\3\sqrt[3]{x+2}.\sqrt[3]{2x-1}(4-x)=(4-x)^3-3x-1\\
27(x+2)(2x-1)(4-x)^3=((4-x)^3-3x-1)^3$$ now you must go to the power of 3 
and solve $ax^9+....=0$ degree=9
but it will be polynomial .

if you solve the eqaution with numerical or graphical method  ,it has a root  $x=1.325$ (the only root )

are you sure that type the equation correct ?

***why there is one real root ? 
  if you take $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+2}+\sqrt[3]{2x-1}+x-4 $ so $$f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{(x+2)^2}}+\dfrac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{(2x-1)^2}}+1 >0$$ so f(x) is strictly increasing $\to $ 
so $$f(x)=0$$ has only one root , It can be checked by 
$$f(1)<0 ,f(1.5)>0 \to x_0 \in (1,1.5)$$ so you can go on

split $(1,1.5) \to (1,1.25) ,(1.25,1.5)$ 
$$f(1)f(1.25)>0 \\f(1.25)f(1.5)<0 \to x_0 \in (1.25,1.5)$$ and take over

Comment: yes, the equation  correct

Comment: @WordShallow :so are you looking for numerical method  ? graphing ?

Comment: There isn't really much more to it. According to maple, the solution $x$ is given in terms of a root $r$ of $p(z)={z}^{9}+3\,{z}^{7}-18\,{z}^{6}+3\,{z}^{5}-36\,{z}^{4}+111\,{z}^{3}-18
\,{z}^{2}+108\,z-221$, which is in fact the only real root of this polynomial. We have $r\simeq 1.4926$ and  $x=r^3-2\simeq1.3255$.

Comment: @ Khosrotash: first choose

Comment: @WordShallow :i edited my answer to use of numerical method

Answer (score 0):

(*Too long for a comment*.)  Building upon this...

> Let $\,\sqrt[3]{x+2}=a\,;\;\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=b$

The canonical way to get the polynomial equation in $x$ is to eliminate $a,b$ between:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
a^3 &= x+2 \\
b^3 &= 2x-1 \\
a+b +x &= 4
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

This is a routine calculation using [polynomial resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Application_to_polynomial_systems), though generally not pretty to do by hand. In this case [`resultant[ resultant[ a+b+x-4, b^3-2x+1, b ], a^3-x-2, a ]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+resultant%5B+a%2Bb%2Bx-4,+b%5E3-2x%2B1,+b+%5D,+a%5E3+-+x+-+2,+a+%5D) gives $x$ as the root of:

$$
x^9 - 36 x^8 + 585 x^7 - 5589 x^6 + 34317 x^5 - 139563 x^4 + 374328 x^3 - 635553 x^2 + 615033 x - 253503 = 0
$$

Numerically, [$x  \;\;\simeq\;\; 1.3254785\dots$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E9+-+36+x%5E8+%2B+585+x%5E7+-+5589+x%5E6+%2B+34317+x%5E5+-+139563+x%5E4+%2B+374328+x%5E3+-+635553+x%5E2+%2B+615033+x+-+253503+%3D+0)

Comment: How to solution $x^9 - 36 x^8 + 585 x^7 - 5589 x^6 + 34317 x^5 - 139563 x^4 + 374328 x^3 - 635553 x^2 + 615033 x - 253503 $ ?

Comment: @WordShallow It's a $9^{th}$ degree equation, you can only solve it numerically.

Answer (score 0):

If we set $a = \sqrt[3]{x+2}$ and $b = \sqrt[3]{2x-1}$, since $a + b = 4 - x = 1 + (3 - x)$, we obtain that

\begin{cases}
a^{3} - b^{3}  = a + b - 1\\
b^{3} = 2a^{3} - 5
\end{cases}

Hence we conclude that $b = 6 - a - a^{3}$, from whence we have the equation
\begin{align*}
(6 - a - a^{3})^{3} = 2a^{3} - 5
\end{align*}
Which can be solved numerically. Wolfram, for example, gives $a \approx 1.49263$